# How to Check 403 Forbidden Error Page?

Tags: forbidden

How can we know whether our server is giving 403 forbidden error perfectly or not? I want to know because I used a code for .htaccess file which is used to block referrer websites and spam bots.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain1\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain2\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain3\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
 </IfModule>
```

I blocked a website using that code but when I visit that website and click on my website link, my website opens fine to me. Shouldn't I receive a 403 forbidden page as the referrer website is listed in .htaccess file?

How can I check whether my website supports 403 forbidden page or not? Is the code correct?

Comment: Check epazote.io probably could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to forge a request. You can use Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/postman) for example, or use a library like curl or request.

In your case, you just have to change the Referer field in the header.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible for a website server to not show 403 forbidden page due to any issue or setting? I just want to make sure that my server is properly showing 403 forbidden page to blocked referrers.

Comment: I am not an apache expert, but your code seems correct. I can't see why a webserver couldn't serve 403 if the rules are written accordingly. You can create a simpler rule to forbid only a certain URL, no matter what the referer is, and test it with your browser.

Comment: Thanks. I used an extension for Chrome to use custom referrer and when I tried with a blocked referrer value, my website showed 403 forbidden page.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I visit that website and click on my website link, my website opens fine to me. Shouldn't I receive a 403 forbidden page as the referrer website is listed in `.htaccess` file?

For a normal link, under normal conditions, yes. You would expect the request to be blocked. However, blocking using the `Referer` (HTTP request header) is *unreliable*.

- The user's browser can be configured to not send the `Referer` header.
- The anchor/link on the source site can be constructed in such a way as to not send the HTTP `Referer`. In fact, with HTML5, you only need to set the `rel="noreferrer"` (two r's) attribute on the anchor to prevent the browser from sending the `Referer` header (part of the Referrer Policy).
- The [Referrer Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) (supported by Chrome and Firefox) allows websites to block all `Referer` headers on all links coming from a website.

(Note, sometimes it's "Referer" (1 r), sometimes "Referrer" (2 r's).)

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033300/stop-link-from-sending-referrer-to-destination

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked with Chrome extension which helps in customizing the referrer and I got 403 forbidden error page. So it means my website server should properly showing the page to blocked referrers.